# shell script executes without passing any required parameters

Tags: bash, shell

I need help figuring out one issue in my script, options ( c, e , d, f and g) are mandatory options in my script and they are always implied before running my script otherwise script wont be executed. Now i have added a  command  and if i tried to to execute my script without any necessary parameters, it'd be still be executed and exit out , my script shouldn't be executing without passing any required parameters but it still does and exits out. how can i fix this?

Thank you in advance,

```
#!/bin/bash


cont=false


options=':c:d:e:f:g:h:i' # additional option characters go here
while getopts $options option
do
    case $option in
        c  ) cont=true;;
        d  ) hello="$OPTARG"
        e  ) hi="$OPTARG"
        f  ) Fri="$OPTARG"
        g  ) Sat="$OPTARG"
        h  ) SUN="$OPTARG"
        i  ) ....so on
        # more option processing can go here

    esac
done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an array called `mandatory` that contains required options and setting the array element to `-` for given options, the code below reports an error for unspecified mandatory options:

```
mandatory=(c d e f g)
options=':c:d:e:f:g:h:i'
while getopts $options option
do
  for ((i = 0 ; i < ${#mandatory[@]} ; i++ )); do
    [[ $option == ${mandatory[$i]} ]] && mandatory[$i]="-"  
  done
  case $option in
      c  ) echo c; cont=true;;
      d  ) hello="$OPTARG";;
      e  ) hi="1"
  esac
done

for ((i = 0 ; i < ${#mandatory[@]} ; i++ )); do
  if [[ ${mandatory[$i]} != '-' ]]; then
    echo "option ${mandatory[$i]} was not given"
    exit 1
  fi
done

if cat /proc/mounts | grep /dev ; then echo "mount exists
   else
   echo "mount doesn't exist"
   exit ; 
fi
```

Comment: how can i integrate my mount command to this? because that's the main issue.

Comment: you are not using any user provided options for mount in your code. how do you use them?

Comment: right, i am not using any options, i am just passing it in my script without any provided options.

Comment: Also, you have set `i = 0 `, is `i` a variable or one of the options i have set in my script?

Comment: if you are not using any arguments, then why are they mandatory?

Comment: `i` is a loop variable, not an option.

Comment: they are mandatory to run the script, issue arises ONLY for my mount command, i want to set it up in a way that if those 5 mandatory options ( c, d, e, f,g) are fulfilled ONLY then my mount command should be executed. can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a colon in front of the options, it is *your* responsibility to handle the error condition.

From `help getopts`:

> If the first character
>       of OPTSTRING is a colon, getopts uses silent error reporting.  In
>       this mode, no error messages are printed.  If an invalid option is
>       seen, getopts places the option character found into OPTARG.  If a
>       required argument is not found, getopts places a ':' into NAME and
>       sets OPTARG to the option character found.

You must handle the case where `$option` contains `:`.